# How do I preserve several sort orders for one List<MyStructure>

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, optimization

I have a custom structure implemented as a class because I need to have a single instance for a single customer. It has quite a few fields, lets say 5 fields:

```
public class SCustomer
{
    public Guid ID;
    public int PriorityIndex;
    public string Name;
    public DateTime BirthDate;
    public double Rating;
}
```

In the business logic I have I often need to sort the lists of those structures i.e. `List<SCustomer>` using different comparison strategies, some are implementer as instance comparers, some are anonymous delegates.

Sorting a single `List` each time I need a new order is not an option due to performance reasons. Maintaining as many lists as many sort orders I need is a pain i.e. I would need keeping them in sync as there are periodical (not frequent) updates to the list and the updates are batch updates.

What is the advised tactic to maintain several sort orders to a set of relational data in .NET?

For reference: List size is about 100 000 items. Update rate is about 1 update per 1000 reading scenario cycles. Update touches about 10% of the records.

Comment: You've mentioned database, why don't you use it?

Comment: As Tim said. And this all very depends on the number of rows, the update frequency, latency of your database, etc.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I do use the database. The thing is I have a need for rather large cache on the .NET side and I need it sorted in several different ways.

Comment: @PatrickHofman There is too much data needed in order to execute the required scenario to request the database each time. Forget the database. I need a solution for the .NET side. I appended the list size estimate and update estimate, thanks.

Comment: The multiple list approach is the worst, because either the list size is small, then this is no issue, or it is large, then it's just a matter of time when your app crashes with an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This is why I need a better solution.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I removed the analogy with the database as it seems it is driving the reader the wrong way.

Comment: @ZverevEugene: afaik you've excluded all viable options: the multi list approach because of high memory and synchronization issues, single list always sorted because of  low performance, the database because you think it's too slow. Why do you need such a large list at all? Normally you select only what is needed and in the desired  order directly from the database.

Comment: "I have a need for a rather large cache". This sounds like your problem. In my experience there are 2 difficult unsolved problems in programming, 1) Caching 2) Naming 3) Off by One Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list of indices for each way of ordering. The lists of indices take less memory space since the are just integers. For example:

```
public class SCustomer
{
    public SCustomer(int ID, string Name)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Name = Name;
    }
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
}

public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    List<SCustomer> people = new List<SCustomer>();
    SCustomer customer1 = new SCustomer (11, "Robert");
    SCustomer customer2 = new SCustomer (5, "Kate");
    SCustomer customer3 = new SCustomer (23, "David");
    people.Add(customer1);
    people.Add(customer2);
    people.Add(customer3);

    List<int> sortingById = new List<int>();
    List<int> sortingByName = new List<int>();
    for(int i=0; i<people.Count; i++)
    {
        sortingById.Add(i);
        sortingByName.Add(i);
    }

    sortingById.Sort( (e1, e2) => people[e1].ID.CompareTo(people[e2].ID) );
    sortingByName.Sort( (e1, e2) => string.Compare(people[e1].Name, people[e2].Name) );

    sortingById.ForEach (x => System.Console.Write (x));
    System.Console.WriteLine ();
    sortingByName.ForEach (x => System.Console.Write (x));

}
```

So as you can see we have `sortingById` and `sortingByName`. In the first position of these lists you will find the index to the lowest element in people (each one according to a different criteria).

If you wanted to add more elements later you would have to insert the new indices to all the set of sorting lists. Since the elements are already sorted you would just need to perform a binary search.

Comment: A reference variable needs also 32 bit (or 64 bit on 64 bit systems). Therefore 100,000 items and 10 different sort orders need just (64 bit = 8 byte; 1,000,000 * 8 byte = 8.000.000 byte = 7 MB). I am not sure if the efford of working with indices instead of references is reasonable (the only advantage is 3.5 MB less memory consumption on 64 bit maschines).

Comment: You are right, there is not much improvement. It's just a different way.

Comment: I like the idea and will give it a try, thanks. May be I should try to keep the index data in `Array`? Preserve some space and expand it when needed...

Answer (score 1):

> Maintaining as many lists as many sort orders I need is a pain i.e. I would need keeping them in sync as there are periodical (not frequent) updates to the list and the updates are batch updates.

You could just create one parent list that internally holds as many lists as sort orders are nedded. The parent list could expose the internall lists with its differnet sort orders (propably as readonly lists). So you have just one interface to manage your items and you can access them in a sorted order at any time.

Note: All lists share the same items, so there is not much memory consumption needed for that solution.